# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting the error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number" when I try to run the below function:

```
public function showAction(Post $post, Request $request){

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setPost($post);

    //comment->setUser($user);

    $form  = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment); /*obiekt formularza */
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if($form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush('success', 'Komentarz został pomyślnie dodany');

        $this->addFlash();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('post_show', array('id' =>$post->getId()));
    }


    return $this->render('default/show.html.twig', array(
        'post' => $post,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

My CommentTye form:

```
class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('content', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Treść komentarza')
        ))
        ->add('createdAt')
        ->add('post')
        ->add('user')
        ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Comment'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'appbundle_comment';
}
}
```

When I run it, I get

```
Message: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO comment (content, created_at, post_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)':
```

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Please help me fix this

Comment: please fix the code-block in your question (use 4-space indentation for code) - it's unreadable like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my first post.

Comment: Try to call `$em->flush()` without parameters. Actually the first and the only parameter is `$entity`, you shouldn't supply 'success' there.

Comment: It doesn't work. And I get new message:     Warning: Missing argument 1 for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::addFlash(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfBlog\sfBlog\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 76 and defined (that 76 line is $this->addFlash(); )

Comment: Remove both strings from `$em->flush()`, and instead, add them to `$this->addFlash('success', 'Komentarz został pomyślnie dodany')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up **flush**ing your entity-manager and adding a **flash** message.

Instead of:

```
$em->flush('success', 'Komentarz został pomyślnie dodany');
$this->addFlash();
```

You want:

```
$em->flush();
$this->addFlash('success');
$this->addFlash('Komentarz został pomyślnie dodany');
```

Comment: I'm in the same exact situation: can you explain why mixing flash messages with flushing operations causes this exception? Because I'm doing this to save both a database version of the message and display it immediately after the page reload. I'd like to know the reason. Thank you!

Comment: If flash messages are stored in the session and the `flush` operation operates on database, which is the relation between the both?

Comment: @Aerendir there is no relation between the two. Symfony's session storage (php-session, memcached, redis, ..) and the DBAL storage (doctrine-orm/odm, ...) are two completely separate layers.

Comment: Yes, you are right... I misread the reply... I know they are completely separate layers, and for this reason I did't understood why flash messages caused the exception on flush... reading again I figured out this not my situation... anyway thank you for your reply.